# using functions to simplify CMS theming

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm in the process of making my own CMS. I have some code that selects database rows to be echoed out on the page like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());
```

However whenever I try to put this inside a function and call the function instead of using that long lines of code, nothing happens. Am I missing something with PHP functions?

```
function posts() {
     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error()); `
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(posts())) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your function code?

Comment: just added the code to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result:

```
function posts() {
     return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts order by id desc") or die(mysql_error()); `
}
```

Comment: Bingo. Currently, you're executing the operation, but wasting the return value which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your function code, it's impossible to say what the problem is, but if I had to guess based on your description, the first thing I'd check is to see if you are (a) returning $query in your function and (b) assigning the return value to something else in your calling code.

UPDATE: So, based on the code you posetd, yes, the problem is (a) above--you need to return the value.  Just put "return" before the rest of the one line of code in the function and it should work.